# Count Number of Entries in a Column Django

Tags: python, django, numbers

I have a counter object defined as

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    counter_text = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

I want to count exactly how many counter objects exist in django.

I am using this as an average, so if there is a better way to average a column, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What instances are you trying to count? And where?

Comment: @crey4fun  I mean how many of the counter objects exist in the database. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an iterable of all the instances of your model, the `all()` method is what you need ([see doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all))

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all()   # returns a queryset
```

If you want to count the numbers of `Counter` instances in your database, thank to the ability of [chaining queries (see doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters), you can just do:

```
>>> Counter.objects.all().count()  # returns an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the amount of Counter rows, you can do it like this:

```
Counter.objects.all().count()
```

This will return the amount of rows as an int.